# Handle date column with spaces in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to  format the date field which contains spaces in replace text processor from a csv file.

Got the error as it is unable to parse the date column which is spaces for first record. Please let me know how to handle this

Error message: Replace text failed to process session due to Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format ddMMyyyy; attribute value:

Input csv:

```
1,        , 123

2,02091997,234
```

Search value : `(.{1}),(.{8}), (.{3})`

Replacement value : `$1, ${'$2':toDate("ddMMyyyy") :format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") }, $3`

Replacement strategy : **Regex Replace**

Evaluation mode : **Entire Text**

Comment: You should look at using Records rather than trying to handle text - see CSVReader https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.13.0/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/index.html - this will be much more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isEmpty` and `ifElse` function from the language expression.

ex: `${'$2':isEmpty():ifElse('null', '$2':toDate("ddMMyyyy"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")) }`

Here I put 'null', when there is no date, but you can choose the value you want.

> However, if you can, parse your CSV files with a **CSVReacordReader** which handle that out of the box.